# Local phase shift of a wavefunction

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, quantum-electrodynamics, aharonov-bohm

**EDIT**: so, the real question is, why did we need LPS invariance to be a feature of QFT in a first place??

Was that a mere reflection of the fact that properties of matter particles are not defined (i.e., superposition) at all points, so that we can't treat them in only 1 of possible ways they interact, but instead in sort of all (or any, LPS-wise) possible ways 
$-$ is *that* the physical meaning of gauge bosons, what they are and what they do??

---

I've just learned from QFT, that EM field is a gauge field  in a way that it is *"compensating"* (as they say) any **local phase shifts (LPS)** in wavefunctions of electrically charged particles - meaning, as I understand, that locally messed up complex sine wave restores all its smoothness.

So I've searched for example of LPS and got familiar with [the Aharonov-Bohm effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect) on Wikipedia, where it says that:

> This phase shift has been observed experimentally.

But... if EM field "compensates" any LPS, then how can any LPS could be "found experimentally" - ?

I mean, it is not a "compensation" of a shift - if that shift can still be found, right?

Or, does that mean that wavefunction of a particle really stays messed up (and, therefore, LPS could be observed), but if one looks at **another** wavefunction, the one that particle may somehow share with... EM field? Or its chunks (photons, I guess) 
 $-$ *then* one sees sine wave "restored all its smoothness".

..I mean, such combination of an electron field and EM field is quite unexpected to me; but may be that is why bosons in SM are called "gauge" after all.

Idk: I'm soo curios with this, I just can't keep going down that rabbit hole without clarification))